# Components in JFrame don't show if followed by starting a Process

Tags: java, swing, exec, event-dispatch-thread

I have the following code (simplified):

```
public class MyForm extends JFrame {
  private SplashForWaiting generating = new SplashForWaiting();
  private String texContent, batContent;

  // boilerplate code
  // ...

  private String insertFormValues(String template) {
    // modify String
  }

  private void buttonGenerateActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    generating.setVisible(true);
    Path texFile = Files.createTempFile(tmpDir,"test", ".tex");
    Path batFile = Files.createTempFile(tmpDir,"test", ".bat");
    OutputStreamWriter batWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(batFile.toFile()), java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("IBM850"));
    batWriter.write(batContent.replace("¦filename",texFile.getFileName().toString()));
    batWriter.close();
    LinkedList<String> cmd = new LinkedList<>();
    cmd.add("explorer"); // cmd.exe is not directly accessible
    cmd.add(batFile.getFileName().toString());
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(texFile.toFile()), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    writer.write(insertFormValues(texContent));
    writer.close();
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
    pb.directory(tmpDir.toFile());
    if (!debug || debugGenerate==true) {
      if (debug) System.out.print("Generating");
      Process p = pb.start();
      int exitval = p.waitFor();
      Path done = tmpDir.resolve("done.txt");
      do {
        if (debug) System.out.print(".");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
      } while (!Files.exists(done));
      Files.delete(done);
      generating.setVisible(false);
    }
  }
}

public class SplashForWaiting extends JFrame {
  private JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel();
  private JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
  public SplashForWaiting() {
    setTitle("Generating...");
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setBounds(new Rectangle((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width-730)/2, (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height-312)/2, 730, 312));
    setIconImages(MyForm.icons);
    setMaximumSize(new Dimension(750, 312));
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(750, 312));
    setResizable(false);
    //setUndecorated(true);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    jPanel1.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(750, 312));
    jPanel1.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(750, 312));
    jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 312));
    jPanel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(jPanel1, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    jLabel2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/generating.jpg")));
    jLabel2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(750, 312));
    jLabel2.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(750, 312));
    jLabel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 312));
    jPanel1.add(jLabel2);

    getContentPane().add(jPanel1);

    pack();
  }              
}
```

As can be seen (though a bit obscured) is that a Windows batch file is created, along with a file to work on, and that that batch file is then executed. While the batch process is running, something like a Splash screen should inform the user what is happening.

The problem is as follows:

- If the program skips running the batch file (`debugGenerate` false), the "Splash" window displays just as intended, but obviously nothing is being generated.
- If the program does run the batch file (`debugGenerate` true), only the decorations (if not undecorated) of the "Splash" window appear, while the inside of the "Splash" window JFrame doesn't display at all. As in, it appears transparent but is actually more like a partial screenshot or area-limited screen-freeze.

Comment: Please read about [concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). This will help you to understand, why your get a screen-freese.

Comment: Tbh, I saw it as quite sequential: 1. Button starts method, 2. Method displays the static Pseudo-Splash image, 3. Method starts the bash file and waits for it to finish, 4. Method hides the Pseudo-Splash. What I mean is, it's not like I'm doing anything to the Pseudo-Splash while the bash file is running, so where does concurrency come in there?

Comment: The problem is, that the splash screen is painting in the thread which is blocked by your "do-while" loop. So no painting is possible during execution of your loop. You need to move your loop into another thread. For example by using of `SwingWorker`. Please read the article from my previous comment.